# Drawing this signal stream in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the following stream with TikZ.
[image]
The problem here is the bottommost line. I have no idea how to draw that row in TikZ.

Here is what I tried and how it looks:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1.2cm, align=center]
    \node[state, line width=0.01mm, fill=examplecolor!20, text width=4mm] (q0) {\large{\textbf{2}}};
    \node[state, right=of q0, line width=0.01mm, fill=examplecolor!20, text width=4mm] (q1) {\large{\textbf{1}}};
    \node[state, right=of q1, line width=0.01mm, fill=examplecolor!20, text width=4mm] (q2) {\large{\textbf{3}}};
    \node[left=of q0] (off0) {$x$};
    \node[right=of q2] (off1) {};

    \node[state, below=of q0, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm] (r0) {\large{\textbf{0}}};
    \node[state, right=of r0, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm] (r1) {\large{\textbf{2}}};
    \node[state, right=of r1, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm] (r2) {\large{\textbf{3}}};
    \node[left=of r0] (off2) {last$(s,x)$};
    \node[right=of r2] (off3) {};

    \node[signal, below=of r0, signal to=east, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm] (s0) {\large{\textbf{0}}};
    \node[signal, right=of s0, signal to=east, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm] (s1) {\large{\textbf{2}}};
    \node[signal, right=of s1, signal to=east, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm] (s2) {\large{\textbf{3}}};
    \node[left=of s0] (off4) {$s$};

    \path[-, line width=0.01mm]
        (q0) edge node {} (q1)
        (q1) edge node {} (q2)
        (r0) edge node {} (r1)
        (r1) edge node {} (r2);

    \path[->, line width=0.01mm]
        (q2) edge node {} (off1)
        (r2) edge node {} (off3);

    \path[|-, line width=0.01mm]
        (off0) edge node {} (q0)
        (off2) edge node {} (r0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code produces the following result:

[image]

Now, it seems that "signal" is not the thing I am looking for at this point, but I can't find anything else to accomplish this task. Has anybody an idea how to draw the last row in TikZ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX. Please next time provide a complete minimum working (or not) example: from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` with all used libraries or packages. In this case `automata` library is missing and also definition of `examplecolor` and `forestgreen(web)` color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calc` library to calculate `minimum width` for `signal` nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, automata,shapes.symbols,calc}

\colorlet{examplecolor}{cyan}
\colorlet{forestgreen(web)}{green}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1.2cm, align=center]
    \node[state, line width=0.01mm, fill=examplecolor!20, text width=4mm] (q0) {\large{\textbf{2}}};
    \node[state, right=of q0, line width=0.01mm, fill=examplecolor!20, text width=4mm] (q1) {\large{\textbf{1}}};
    \node[state, right=of q1, line width=0.01mm, fill=examplecolor!20, text width=4mm] (q2) {\large{\textbf{3}}};
    \node[left=of q0] (off0) {$x$};
    \node[right=of q2] (off1) {};

    \node[state, below=of q0, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm] (r0) {\large{\textbf{0}}};
    \node[state, right=of r0, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm] (r1) {\large{\textbf{2}}};
    \node[state, right=of r1, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm] (r2) {\large{\textbf{3}}};
    \node[left=of r0] (off2) {last$(s,x)$};
    \node[right=of r2] (off3) {};

    \path let \p1=($(r0.center)-(off2.east)$), \n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in node[draw, signal, below left= 1.2cm and 0pt of r0.center, signal to=east, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm, anchor=east, minimum width=\n2] (s0) {\large{\textbf{0}}};

    \path let \p1=($(r1.center)-(r0.center)$), \n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in node[draw, signal, right= 0pt of s0.east, anchor=west, signal to=east and west, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm, minimum width=\n2] (s1) {\large{\textbf{2}}};

    \path let \p1=($(r2.center)-(r1.center)$), \n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in node[draw, signal, right=0pt of s1.east, anchor=west, signal to=east and west, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm, minimum width=\n2] (s2) {\large{\textbf{3}}};

    \path let \p1=($(off3.center)-(r2.center)$), \n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in node[draw, signal, right=0pt of s2.east, anchor=west, signal to=west, line width=0.01mm, fill=forestgreen(web)!20, text width=4mm, minimum width=\n2] (s2) {\large{\textbf{6}}};

    \node[anchor=east] at (off2.east|-s1) {$s$};

    \path[-, line width=0.01mm]
        (q0) edge node {} (q1)
        (q1) edge node {} (q2)
        (r0) edge node {} (r1)
        (r1) edge node {} (r2);

    \path[->, line width=0.01mm]
        (q2) edge node {} (off1)
        (r2) edge node {} (off3);

    \path[|-, line width=0.01mm]
        (off0) edge node {} (q0)
        (off2) edge node {} (r0);
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

[image]